# Need a javascript regex to match a specific path

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need help to match a url that matches only if

- the path matches exactly /gummybear/ or /gummybear (case sensetive)
- the protocol is http or https
- the domain/host/port/hash can be anything

the regex **should not** match if

- the path is /gummybear/foobar
- it contains search parameters such as ?query=string

So far i got this:

```
/^http[s]?:\/\/?[^\/\s]+\/gummybear[\/]?/
```

examples it should be true for

```
https://www.example.com:81/gummybear/
http://www.example.com/gummybear#top
https://example.com:81/gummybear#/foobar/?search=params
http://www.exa.mple.com:81/gummybear
https://example.com:81/gummybear/#/exaple/1234/
```

examples that it should be false for

```
https://www.example.com:81/foo/gummybear/
https://www.example.com:81/guMmybear/
https://www.example.com:81/gummybear.html
http://www.example.com/gummybear/apple#top
file://example.com:81/gummybear#/foobar/?search=params
http://www.exa.mple.com:81/gummybear?search=apple#lol
https://example.com:81/#/gummybear/
http://www.test.com:81/dir/dir.2/index.htm?q1=0&&test1&test2=value#top
```

Comment: What are the differences between your "should match" `https://example.com:81/gummybear/#/exaple/1234/` and your "shouldn't match" `the path is /gummybear/foobar` ?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza it matches another sub directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your specific needs, I can come up with this regex:

```
^https?://[^/]+/gummybear(?:/?|/?#.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE0bH2/1)**

[image]

I haven't escaped slashes to make it more readable, but for javascript you can use:

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/gummybear(?:\/?|\/?#.*)$
```

Comment: what tool did you use to generate that diagram? is it on regex101? where?

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly I used [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gtaOxRLtbnc1USP5)